# std::vector of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, compiler-errors

Following declaration passes compilation check:

```
int arr[3];
vector<int[3]> vec;  // ok !!
```

When trying to use `vec` practically as,

```
vec.push_back(arr);
```

it results in many error like:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ext/new_allocator.h:108:9: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization in array new [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc:314:4: error: invalid array assignment 
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ext/new_allocator.h:118:30: error: request for member ‘~int [3]’ in ‘* __p’, which is of non-class type ‘int [3]’
```

Additionally, `vec` doesn't `push_back()` the `int*` also.

What exactly goes wrong here ? Is such issue being addressed in C++11 ?

Comment: You can't store arrays in containers because they are not assignable. The assignment operator is only attempted when you do `push_back` which is why your code compiles without it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, you are correct. That should be an answer. I missed the fact that arrays are not assignable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't store arrays in containers because they are neither assignable nor copyable, which are the requirements for all objects that are used with Standard Library containers.

The assignment operator is only attempted when you do `push_back()` which is why your code **compiles without it**.

Comment: Does this still apply with emplace_back?

Answer (score 10):

The basic requirement of Standard library containers is that the elements should be **Copy constructible** and **Assignable**.

Arrays are not assignable and hence the error, You cannot use them as Standard library container elements.

Reference:

**C++03 Standard:23.1 Container requirements       [lib.container.requirements]**

**Para 3:**

> The type of objects stored in these components must meet the requirements of **CopyConstructible** types (20.1.3), and the additional requirements of **Assignable types.**

Answer (score 6):

`vector`s, like any other containers, are unable to store arrays, for the same reasons that you can't assign an array to another array. You have a couple of alternatives:

- The obvious one is to use an `std::vector< std::vector<int> >`.
- If you want a more C++11 solution, you may find it better to have an `std::vector` of [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). You would then have `vec` be of type `std::vector< std::array<int, 3> >` .