# C++ Unable to populate a map of C arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, typedef

```
typedef std::map<std::string,int> string2intMap;
typedef string2intMap arrOfMaps[3] ;

//map : string --> array of maps of <std::string,int>
std::map<std::string,arrOfMaps> tryingStuff;

//map : string --> int
string2intMap s;
s["key"]= 100;

tryingStuff["hello"][0] = s;
```

---

The above code does not compile, the problematic line is :
tryingStuff["hello"][0] = s;

here is what the compiler shouts :

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(215): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty> [3]'
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Kty=std::string,
2>              _Ty=int
2>          ]
2>          There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions to references or pointers to arrays
2>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(210) : while compiling class template member function 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty> (&std::map<_Kty,arrOfMaps>::operator [](const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &))[3]'
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Kty=std::string,
2>              _Ty=int,
2>              _Elem=char,
2>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
2>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
2>          ]
2>          c:\work\toot\tootcode\tootim\tools\doobim\doobim.cpp(95) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Kty=std::string,
2>              _Ty=arrOfMaps
2>          ]
2>
2>Build FAILED.
2>
2>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.38
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 5 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any idea how to make it work??
 (I don't want to change the data structure which is a
map : string --> array of maps of  )

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::vector of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557579/stdvector-of-an-array)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot store C-style arrays in containers because they are not assignable; you cannot do this:

```
int x[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };
int y[3] = { 3, 4, 5 };

x = y;
```

But containers need to be able to assign/copy the elements that they're storing.

Consider using a `std::vector` or a `boost::array`<sup>*</sup> instead of a raw C array.

---

<sub>* This can be found as `std::array` in more recent revisions of the C++ standard.</sub>

Comment: Or if you have TR1, `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically array are not copyable.
What you want to use was a vector...

```
typedef std::map<std::string,int>  string2intMap;
typedef std::vector<string2intMap> arrOfMaps;

//map : string --> array of maps of <std::string,int>
std::map<std::string,arrOfMaps>    tryingStuff;

//map : string --> int
string2intMap s;
s["key"]= 100;

tryingStuff["hello"].push_back(s);
```